# Is there a way to upload file directly with rest api?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I want to be able to upload the files directly to the server from a local machine with the a simple URL as below.Is there a way to achieve that?

http://www.example.com/uploadfile/filename

Answer (score 0):

yes, i.e. using `curl` and then handling it in Play as common form data, other obvious way is just using common form...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on [body parsers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaBodyParsers) to see how to parse different kinds of content. One example illustrates how to save a file on disk.